# constexpr keywork doesn't affect on code generation

Tags: c++11, g++, compiler-optimization

I wrote a simple program:

```
constexpr int strlen_c(char const* s)
{
    return *s ? 1 + strlen_c(s + 1) : 0;
}

int main()
{
    return strlen_c("hello world");
}
```

I expected that the compiler optimizes the function and evaluates its result in compile time. But actually the generated machine code evaluates the result in a loop:

```
    mov     edx, offset aHelloWorld ; "hello world"
loc_408D00:
    add     edx, 1
    mov     eax, edx
    sub     eax, offset aHelloWorld ; "hello world"
    cmp     byte ptr [edx], 0
    jnz     short loc_408D00
    leave
    retn
```

The program is being compiled with g++ version 5.3 with flags `-std=c++11 -Ofast -O2`. The same result I obtain in Visual Studio 2013, and g++ 4.9.

**Quaestion** what is the reason the compiler couldn't optimize the given code?

Comment: Both g++ and clang++ optimize the code out. It depends on the compiler implementation.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo can you say a version of g++ and necessary compilation flags?

Comment: GCC 6, ICC 16, and Clang 3.1 all simply load the value 11 and return. These can be found on the interactive disassembly site [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/). Also Microsoft C++ 19.10 (I don't know which Visual Studio), which fails to optimize even for Dinesh's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constexpr function is not necessarily always evaluated at compile time. However, it must be evaluated at compile time if used in a constexpr context, So, following will work regardless of the compiler optimizations:

```
int main()
{
   constexpr auto len = strlen_c("hello world");
   return len;
}
```

Following is the assembly generated for the above code:

```
main:
        mov     eax, 11
        ret
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/uCL9Kk)

Comment: Microsoft's compiler [still executes](https://godbolt.org/g/bOkR4w) `strlen_c` at runtime. Then it discards the result and returns the constant 11. The standard makes no performance guarantees…